# parsing a text file and designing a report using python

Tags: python, html, report

I have a technical question and I need your advice about it.

I need to design a report that contains tables and statistic figures. The data is extracted from HTML file using python. I know how to parse HTML file in python using (beautiful soap). But what is an appropriate way in your opinion to design a good report with colors, tables, and grids and then using the information that is extracted from an HTML file into this report? Is it possible to use the only python? I really need some experts opinion.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Xlsx writer package is the best I have used. You can find the docs and more info here https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io

Comment: You are welcome!